# Auto Update fail time my external folder deleted

Tags: automatic-updates, backup

We have use some code action using wordpress root on external folder with code files. Now wordpress auto update allow on backend now my update fails thats time my directory deleted.

So how to access this folder in backup. Please say me wordpress update time generate auto backup and restored if fails?

So how to add this external folder.

Comment: More info should not be in a link but in your question

Comment: u have edit this question in place minus point. ok i have deleted this info.